# Firebase error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Too many disjunctions after normalization, the maximum is 30

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am running a Javascript cloud function on Firebase to a collection which includes 4 where statements, 2 using "==" and 2 using "in", and then a get. I then receive the error message "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Too many disjunctions after normalization, the maximum is 30". I have googled this error, but not a single hit!

Here is the get statement;

```
const output = await db.collection('object_relationships')
        .where('parent_id', 'in', ["g4gt4554y54y544y54", "jk88i7i8i87i87i87i", "vfdvfd32e3232", "bgfbfgr432r43", "bngbgfg2332rr23"])
        .where('type', '==', 'worker')
        .where('child_id', '==', "hjew7843yu3r783y3r783r")
        .where('text', 'in', ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"])
        .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the issue. This page here is really great: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limits_on_or_queries, it provides some very specific examples of how many disjunctions you have when combining '==' and 'in'. In my case, I had about 5 in my first 'in' and 7 in my 2nd 'in'. 6*8=48 which breaches the 30 max.